# ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (Windows)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to install the object-detection module of tensorflow but when running the following command:

> python3 object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py

I get the following error. I have installed CUDA 8.0,9.0,9.1, and cuDNN 6 and 7 but still have the following error. I appreciate your advice, thank you!

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>   _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>   _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
>   return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
>   return _load(spec)
>   ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py", line 18, in 
>   import tensorflow as tf
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/init.py", line 24, in 
>   from tensorflow.python import *
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/init.py", line 49, in 
>   from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
>   raise ImportError(msg)
>   ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>   _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>   _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
>   return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
>   return _load(spec)
>   ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Comment: I have tried to use sudo apt-get install cuda-9-0 as suggested but I get the following error: 
E: Unable to locate package cuda-9-0

Comment: how did you solve this? I'm suddenly having this issue

Comment: @ kRazzy R  I solved it by running “export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64”. I also did “sudo apt-get install cuda-9.0” instead of “sudo apt-get install cuda-9-0”. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Please answer this. I am dalso facing this error

Answer (score 2):

Put your cuda path into environment variable.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

put this line into your bash profile and update it with **source .bash_profile**.
Open new terminal and run it again. if you get the same error, take a look at this [**solution**](https://ai-pool.com/d/importerror_libcublas_so_9_0).

One more thing can also happen. You may have problem with old installations. make sure you've removed all old version of tensorflow and cuda. (I mean old installation in your pc). Install the version you want on a clean space. If it's not working as well, take a look at this [**solution**](https://ai-pool.com/d/tensorflow_1_13_does_not_use_gpu)